# VueJS Element Reference Not Found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ref

in VueJS I am wanting to reference a modal element via `ref` attribute in VueJS. I've used them before, but in this set up something's not right making it not work and gives the error:

`TypeError: this.$refs.modal is undefined`

I am accessing the reference via the app.js file.

here's my main app.vue template code:

```
    <template>
    <main class="main" id='app'>
        <div v-if="$root.bLoading" class="page-loader">
            <div class="page-loader__spinner">
                <svg viewBox="25 25 50 50">
                    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span v-else v-cloak>
            <header-nav></header-nav>
            <router-view></router-view>
            <footer></footer>
        </span>
        <main-modal ref="modal"></main-modal>
    </main>
</template>
```

Here's my app.js code trying to access the reference:

```
 let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        render:h=>h(App),
        data : function(){
            return {

            }
        },
        router,
        methods : {
            showModal : function(modal_name="",modal_data={}){
                this.$refs.modal.showModal(modal_name,modal_data);
            },
        }
    });
```

Why is this reference element not being found??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `ref="modal"` is part of `App` component and you are trying to access that referenced component from your root instance. The instance `ref` is not available outside of the component **App**. Try moving your `showModal` method inside **App** component.

*Note: there is some discrepancy with your code. Your `#app` element has a template and at the same time, you are using `render` function which is supposed to render `App` component. That is contradictory. Is your template in the example really part of **Root Instance** or **App** component?*

Comment: the template is part of the `App.vue` component. should I add a `template:` in app component? It cannot run properly without have the `render` and `el` properties there in `app.js`

Comment: @zatyh, Remove `id='app'` And create another other dom element with this ID where your root instance can mount. Also, move the method `showModal` to App Component instead of Root Instance.

Comment: Hey, thanks I did what you said it works, really appreciate it Harshal